# Easiest way to display SQL query results on a wordpress site in a paragraph of text?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I would like to get the results of a sql query in a text output and embed that in a sentence on a wordpress page.

I have tried using google apps script to run a sql query and convert the result to html or text, but it seems like html or text can only be embedded in an iframe, which will not work.

Willing to try other methods/free software, I am very much a programming novice so I'm sure there are things I don't know that might be able to help do this.

Comment: Is the query from a WordPress DB table?

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but I'm going to say it's not possible to connect SQL to wordpress. To get PHP to even attempt to talk to SQL you need sqlsrv drivers installed on the machine hosting the site. My recommendation would be get access to you're MySQL database that's included with your wordpress site, and manage things through there.

If you have the ability to FTP into your host, you can write custom php functions that talk to your MySql database and do what you're thinking.

Comment: Every implementation of WordPress has it's own SQL database. What do you mean when you say it's not possible to connect SQL to WordPress?

Comment: They have MySql not SQL.